# How can I turn this existing json into a GraphQL endpoint?

Tags: json, node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js

I am creating an application that takes in data from an api, and I need to easily access that remote data. Currently, my gameplan is to download the json file from the endpoint when a user needs the data, but if someone can recommend a way to use the remote url as a GraphQL source I'd appreciate that as well.

On to the problem at hand:

I am not sure how I should structure my schema.js file. Here is the actual data that I am trying to use [actual data](http://games.espn.com/ffl/api/v2/boxscore?leagueId=1150587&seasonId=2017&teamId=5&scoringPeriodId=7)

but here is a rough outline that I put together. It more or less outlines all of the nested dictionaries and lists that I am having trouble accessing. If someone could provide me with a couple examples of how to reach these nested dicts, lists, and values I would greatly appreciate it!

```
{
boxscore {
  progames {
  },
teams {
  [
    slots {

    },
    appliedStats : float,
    appliedStats1: float,
    team {
      [
        rank: int,
        player {

        },
        watch: boolean,
        trade: boolean,
        currentProjStats {

        },
        proGameIds {

        }
      ],
      [
        ...
      ],
      [
        ...
      ],
    },
    teamId: int,
    appliedActive: int,
    appliedProjActive: float,
  ],
  [

  ]
  }
 }
}
```

Here is an example of what I have attempted

```js
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLFloat
} = require('graphql');
const axios = require('axios');






const PlayerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Player',
  fields:() => ({
    droppable: {type:GraphQLBoolean},
    percentStarted: {type:GraphQLFloat},
    jersey: {type:GraphQLString},
    playerRatingSeason: {type:GraphQLFloat},
    positionRank: {type:GraphQLInt},
    isIREligible: {type:GraphQLBoolean},
    draftRank: {type:GraphQLInt},
    value: {type:GraphQLInt},
    universeId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    firstName: {type:GraphQLString},
    elligibleSlotsCategoryIds: {type:elligibleSlotsCategoryIdsType},
    gameStarterStatus: {type:GraphQLInt},
    lastName: {type:GraphQLString},
    sportsId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    healthStatus: {type:GraphQLInt},
    percentOwned: {type:GraphQLFloat},
    proTeamId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    tickerId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    isActive: {type:GraphQLBoolean},
    playerId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    percentChange: {type:GraphQLFloat},
    defaultPositionId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    totalPoints: {type:GraphQLFloat}
  })
});


const CurrentPeriodProjectedStatsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'CurrentPeriodProjectedStats',
  fields: () => ({
    appliedProjectedStatTotal: {type:GraphQLFloat},
  })
});

const ProGameIdsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'ProGameIds',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {type:GraphQLInt},
  })
});

const CurrentPeriodRealStatsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'CurrentPeriodRealStats',
  fields: () => ({
    appliedRealStatTotal: {type:GraphQLFloat},
  })
});

const SlotsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Slots',
  fields:() => ({
    // This might take type:GraphQLList, not sure though //
    pvoRank: {type: GraphQLInt},
    player: {type: PlayerType},
    watchList: {type:GraphQLBoolean},
    isKeeper: {type:GraphQLBoolean},
    isTradeLocked: {type:GraphQLBoolean},
    currentPeriodProjectedStats: {type: CurrentPeriodProjectedStats},
    proGameIds: {type: ProGameIds},
    opponentProTeamId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    slotCategoryId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    lockStatus: {type:GraphQLInt},
    isQueuedWaiverLocked: {type:GraphQLBoolean},
    currentPeriodRealStats: {type:CurrentPeriodRealStatsType}
  })
});
/*
const ProgamesType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Progames',
  field: () => ({

  })
});
*/

const TeamsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Teams',
  fields: {
    team1: {type:GraphQLList},
    team2: {type:GraphQLList},
  }
});

const BoxscoreType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Boxscore',
  fields: () => ({
  //  progames: {type:ProgamesType},
    teams: () => GraphQLList(TeamsType),
    scoringPeriodId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    matchupPeriodId: {type:GraphQLInt},
    homeTeamBonus: {type:GraphQLInt}
  })
});

const MetadataType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Metadata',
  fields: () => ({
    leagueId: {type:GraphQLString},
    status: {type:GraphQLString},
    seasonId: {type:GraphQLString}
  })
});


const EspnQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'EspnQueryType',
  fields: {
    boxscore: {type:BoxscoreType},
  },
  resolve(parentValue, args){

  }
});



// Keep at the bottom //
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: EspnQuery
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue I see in your code is that you're trying to add a resolver for Query (EspnQuery). Even though it's defined as a `GraphQLObjectType`, because it sits at the root, it's resolver is never called. What you want to do is wrap the existing data structure inside some kind of field for `EspnQuery`:

```
const BoxscoreDataType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'BoxscoreData',
  fields: {
    boxscore: {type:BoxscoreType},
    metadata: {type:MetadataType},
  },
});

const EspnQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'EspnQuery',
  fields: {
    getBoxscore: {
      type: BoxscoreDataType,
      resolve: () => {} // We'll come back to this in a minute
    },
  },
});
```

For testing purposes, you can put your sample JSON data in a separate file and just `require` it:

```
const testData = require('./testData.json')
```

This will return an Object that you can just return inside your resolver for the `getBoxscore` query.

```
resolve: () => testData
```

But we want to return data from the API call, so let's do that instead:

```
resolve: () => {
  const url = 'http://games.espn.com/ffl/api/v2/boxscore?leagueId=1150587&seasonId=2017&teamId=5&scoringPeriodId=7'
  return axios(url)
}
```

Axios returns a Promise, which is great because our resolver can return either a value, or a Promise that will resolve in that value. Just make sure you don't forget the `return`!

#### Bonus: Using Arguments

You can also define arguments for any fields, that can then be used inside the resolver. So `getBoxscore` could look like this:

```
getBoxscore: {
  type: BoxscoreDataType,
  args: {
    leagueId: {
      name: 'leagueId',
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
    },
    seasonId: {
      name: 'seasonId',
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
    },
    teamId: {
      name: 'teamId',
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
    },
    scoringPeriodId: {
      name: 'scoringPeriodId',
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
    }
  }
  resolve: (obj, { leagueId, seasonId, teamId, scoringPeriodId }) => {
    const url = `http://games.espn.com/ffl/api/v2/boxscore?leagueId=${leageId}&seasonId=${seasonId}&teamId=${teamId}&scoringPeriodId=${scoringPeriodId}`
    return axios(url)
  }
}
```

#### Bonus 2: Resolvers

Also, don't forget that part of what makes GraphQL so powerful is the ability to manipulate how your data is returned at the field level. So, for any field, you can easily manipulate the data being returned by the parent object before returning it to the client.

A silly example might be attaching a resolver on firstName in your PlayerType:

```
resolve: ({ firstName }) => {
  return firstName.toUpperCase()
}
```

A more interesting use might be making additional calls to different API endpoints. For example, for the `player` field on SlotsType, you could attach a resolver like this:

```
resolve: ({ player: { playerId } }) => {
    const url = `some url that uses that ${playerId}`
    return axios(url)
}
```

Of course, if you did that, you would probably also modify your `PlayerType` to reflect the data being returned by that call.

There's a ton of possibilities worth exploring. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect! I am having another issue, but it is more than likely due to my graphql noob-ness. Could I shoot you a message for help?

Comment: I'll be off and on for the next 6 hours. Feel free to ping me on here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157840/graphql